# Trying to calculate double-declining depreciation using python nested for-next loops

Tags: python, for-loop

**The code is supposed to output the following, but the calculations are wrong:**

Description: computer
Year of purchase: 2008
Cost: $1500
Estimated life of item (years): 5
Method of depreciation: Double-Declining Balance

Value at the beginning of 2008: $1,500.00
Amount of depreciation during 2008: $600.00
Total depreciation during 2008: $600.00

Value at the beginning of 2009: $900.00
Amount of depreciation during 2009: $360.00
Total depreciation during 2009: $960.00

Value at the beginning of 2010: $540.00
Amount of depreciation during 2010: $216.00
Total depreciation during 2010: $1,176.00

Value at the beginning of 2011: $324.00
Amount of depreciation during 2011: $129.60
Total depreciation during 2011: $1,305.60

Value at the beginning of 2012: $194.40
Amount of depreciation during 2012: $194.40
Total depreciation during 2012: $1,500.00

````
desc_of_item=input("Enter the description of the item: ")
yr_of_purchase=int(input("Enter the year of purchase: "))
cost=int(input("Enter the cost: $"))
estimated_life=int(input("Enter the estimated life (in years): "))
dep_method=int(input("""Enter the value corresponding to the vdepreciation method you want to use:
1. Straight-Light
2. Double-Declining Balance
Here: """))
if dep_method==1:
  depreciation=1/estimated_life*cost
  print(f"The depreciation of {desc_of_item} using the straight-line method is: ${depreciation}")
elif dep_method==2:
  print(f"""Description: {desc_of_item}
  Year of purchase: {yr_of_purchase}
  Cost: ${cost}
  Estimated life of item (years): {estimated_life}
  Method of depreciation: Double-Declining Balance
  """)
  first_depreciation=(2/estimated_life)*cost
  print(f"""Value at the beginning of {yr_of_purchase}: {cost}
  Amount of depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: {first_depreciation}
  Total depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: {first_depreciation}
  """)
  current_value=cost-first_depreciation
  total_depreciation=0+first_depreciation
  for i in range(0,estimated_life-1):
    depreciation=(2/estimated_life)*current_value
    total_depreciation+=depreciation
    current_value=current_value-depreciation
    yr_of_purchase+=1
    print(f"""Value at the beginning of {yr_of_purchase}: ${current_value}
  Amount of depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: ${depreciation}
  Total depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: ${depreciation}
  """)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWDyW.png
````

Comment: your code has errors, some variables you are using not available, fix those, also provide sample example how to calculate the vaules you are expecting

Comment: The first year depreciation is 600, not 300, so the end-of-year book value is 900. Otherwise you could not compute a 2nd year depr of 360 (40% of 900)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few changes to your code, I was able to get the desired results.

I added a check for the current_value being below the straight line depreciation (for the double declining balance calcs) and if it was, to use the current_value as the depreciation for the year.

```
desc_of_item=input("Enter the description of the item: ")
yr_of_purchase=int(input("Enter the year of purchase: "))
cost=int(input("Enter the cost: $"))
estimated_life=int(input("Enter the estimated life (in years): "))
dep_method=int(input("""Enter the value corresponding to the vdepreciation method you want to use:
1. Straight-Light
2. Double-Declining Balance
Here: """))
if dep_method==1:
  depreciation=1/estimated_life*cost
  print(f"The depreciation of {desc_of_item} using the straight-line method is: ${depreciation}")
elif dep_method==2:
  print(f"""Description: {desc_of_item}
  Year of purchase: {yr_of_purchase}
  Cost: ${cost}
  Estimated life of item (years): {estimated_life}
  Method of depreciation: Double-Declining Balance
  """)
  depreciation=(2/estimated_life)*cost
  print(f"""Value at the beginning of {yr_of_purchase}: {cost}
Amount of depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: {depreciation}
Total depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: {depreciation}\n""")
  current_value=cost-depreciation
  total_depreciation=0+depreciation
  yr_of_purchase += 1
  for i in range(0,estimated_life-1):
    if current_value < cost/estimated_life:
        depreciation = current_value
    else:
        depreciation=(2/estimated_life)*current_value
    total_depreciation+=depreciation
    print(f"""Value at the beginning of {yr_of_purchase}: ${current_value}""")
    current_value=current_value-depreciation
    print(f"""Amount of depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: ${depreciation}
Total depreciation during {yr_of_purchase}: ${total_depreciation}\n""")
    yr_of_purchase+=1
```

Prints:

```
Enter the description of the item: computer
Enter the year of purchase: 2008
Enter the cost: $1500
Enter the estimated life (in years): 5
Enter the value corresponding to the vdepreciation method you want to use:
1. Straight-Light
2. Double-Declining Balance
Here: 2
Description: computer
  Year of purchase: 2008
  Cost: $1500
  Estimated life of item (years): 5
  Method of depreciation: Double-Declining Balance
  
Value at the beginning of 2008: 1500
Amount of depreciation during 2008: 600.0
Total depreciation during 2008: 600.0

Value at the beginning of 2009: $900.0
Amount of depreciation during 2009: $360.0
Total depreciation during 2009: $960.0

Value at the beginning of 2010: $540.0
Amount of depreciation during 2010: $216.0
Total depreciation during 2010: $1176.0

Value at the beginning of 2011: $324.0
Amount of depreciation during 2011: $129.6
Total depreciation during 2011: $1305.6

Value at the beginning of 2012: $194.4
Amount of depreciation during 2012: $194.4
Total depreciation during 2012: $1500.0
```